# Enums reference a class Java

Tags: java, random, enums

I have an enum in a Terrain class which lists the available units such as Destroyer, Cruiser, Aegis Cruiser ext, and I am generating units so I choose a random enum from the unit list then I want to create that unit like this `Unit test = new RandomEnumUnit();` 
As a side note the `Terrain` class extends to the `Unit` class.

How can I add attributes or make the enums reference to the units class?

Comment: [Java enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can't really "put classes in an enum", if you want to use an `enum`, you have to do something like that:

```
final Random rand = new Random();

enum UnitType {
    Destroyer, Cruiser, AegisCruiser
}

public Unit newRandomEnumUnit() throws Exception {
    final UnitType selectedUnitType = UnitType.values()[rand.nextInt(UnitType.values().length)];
    switch (selectedUnitType) {
    case Destroyer:
        return new Destroyer();
    case Cruiser:
        return new Cruiser();
    case AegisCruiser:
        return new AegisCruiser();
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unit type not found !");
    }
}
```

and call it like that:

```
Unit test = newRandomEnumUnit();
```

But, if you have a lot of classes, you will have to add a lot of `case` in the `switch`, so instead, you can use an array of classes and a little bit of reflection, like that:

```
final Random rand = new Random();

final static Class<?>[] units = {Destroyer.class, Cruiser.class, AegisCruiser.class};

public Unit newRandomUnit() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    final Class<?> selectedUnitClass = units[rand.nextInt(units.length)];
    return (Unit)selectedUnitClass.newInstance();
}
```

and call it like that:

```
Unit test = newRandomUnit();
```

Just be sure that all your classes are extending `Unit`, and that they all have an empty constructor.